# Xcode Application Loader - communications error

Tags: xcode, application-loader

Attempting to upload a binary that has passed 'validation' I get:

```
Communications error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity. You need to have outbound access to TCP port 443
    An exception has occurred: sun.security.validator.Validator.Exception: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    Could not connect to Apple's web service
    Unable to authenticate the package: 617269104.itms
    Transport update failed with unexpected exception
    An exception has occurred: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.ceertpath.SunCertPathBuilder\exception: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I still have this problem despite trying all the suggestions in various similar SO threads. Running App Loader 2.9.1; Java version 7 build 1.7.0.; Yosemite beta 4; Xcode 5.1.1. Also tried all the settings in Java Control Panel General/Network Settings. All firewall ports open for outbound traffic.

Any new/further suggestions appreciated...